# Issue regarding posting data to controller using jquery $.post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have two dropdown one for country and another one for state. when first time form render then country dropdown is populated and state dropdown is disable. when user select country then a partial post occur by jquery and a controller action method is called which return json data. problem occur when user select country then i saw my overloaded index method is called and it return json but firebug is showing error like network error.

here i am giving my controller code and cshtml code. please tell me what is wrong there

```
cshtml code

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        //        $('#CountryID').change(function () {
        //            var URL = $('#FormID');
        //            alert(URL);
        ////            $.getJSON('/DDL/DistrictList/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
        //            });
        //        });


        $('#CountryID').change(function () {
            var dropdownID = $(this).val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', { CountryID: dropdownID }, function (result) {
                // result contains your State-List
                var items = '<option>--Select State--</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                    alert(i);
                    items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#State').html(items);

            });
        });
    });
</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>DropDownList</legend>
        @Html.Label("Country")
        @Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.Country as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { id = "CountryID" })

        @Html.Label("State")
        @Html.DropDownList("State", ViewBag.Country as SelectList, "--Select State--", new { id = "StateID", @disabled = "disabled" })

        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="SubmitId" />
    </fieldset>
}

controller code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CascadeTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to Cascade Test";
            ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(CascadeTest.Models.Country.GetCountries(), "CountryID", "Name");

            var State = from s in CascadeTest.Models.State.GetState()
                        where s.CountryID == ""
                        select s.Name;

            ViewBag.State = new SelectList(State, "StateID", "Name");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(string CountryID)
        {
            var State = from s in CascadeTest.Models.State.GetState()
                        where s.CountryID == CountryID
                        select s.Name;
            string xxx = Json(new SelectList(State.ToArray(), "StateID", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet).ToString();
            return Json(new SelectList(State.ToArray(), "StateID", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}

my model code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CascadeTest.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<Country> GetCountries()
        {
            return new List<Country>
            {
                new Country {
                    CountryID = "CA",
                    Name = "Canada"
                },
                new Country{
                    CountryID = "US",
                    Name = "United States"
                },
                new Country{
                    CountryID = "UK",
                    Name = "United Kingdom"
                },
                new Country{
                CountryID = "IN",
                Name = "India"
                }
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }

    public class State
    {
        public string StateID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryID { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<State> GetState()
        {
            return new List<State>
            {
                // State declare for india
                new State {
                    StateID = "WB",
                    Name = "West Bengal"
                    ,CountryID="IN"
                },
                new State{
                    StateID = "BH",
                    Name = "Bihar"
                    ,CountryID="IN"
                },
                new State{
                    StateID = "OR",
                    Name = "Orissa"
                    ,CountryID="IN"
                },
                new State{
                StateID = "MD",
                Name = "Madhya Pradesh"
                ,CountryID="IN"
                },

                // State declare for USA
                new State{
                StateID = "AL",
                Name = "Alabama"
                ,CountryID="US"
                },

                new State{
                StateID = "FL",
                Name = "Florida"
                ,CountryID="US"
                },

                new State{
                StateID = "IA",
                Name = "Iowa"
                ,CountryID="US"
                },

                new State{
                StateID = "MS",
                Name = "Mississippi"
                ,CountryID="US"
                },

                // State declare for UK
                new State{
                StateID = "AV",
                Name = "Avon"
                ,CountryID="UK"
                },

                new State{
                StateID = "BS",
                Name = "Buckinghamshire"
                ,CountryID="UK"
                },


                new State{
                StateID = "CH",
                Name = "Cheshire"
                ,CountryID="UK"
                },

                new State{
                StateID = "DS",
                Name = "Dorset"
                ,CountryID="UK"
                }

                //No state define for canada
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

i think the problem lies here in below code

```
$('#CountryID').change(function () {
            var dropdownID = $(this).val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', { CountryID: dropdownID }, function (result) {
                // result contains your State-List
                var items = '<option>--Select State--</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                    alert(i);
                    items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#State').html(items);

            });
        });
```

here is the error line firefox is showing

[image]

i am not being able to understand what i am doing wrong. so please help me to fix this problem. thanks

### How my index method look like

one is default without argument and second index method is called to populate state when country is selected. when country is selected then a partial post occur by jquery and second index method return json from server side which jquery parse to populate state dropdown. please have look at the code and tell me where i need to change. thanks

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to Cascade Test";
            ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(CascadeTest.Models.Country.GetCountries(), "CountryID", "Name");

            var State = from s in CascadeTest.Models.State.GetState()
                        where s.CountryID == ""
                        select s.Name;

            ViewBag.State = new SelectList(State, "StateID", "Name");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(string CountryID)
        {
            var State = from s in CascadeTest.Models.State.GetState()
                        where s.CountryID == CountryID
                        select s.Name;
            string xxx = Json(new SelectList(State.ToArray(), "StateID", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet).ToString();
            return Json(new SelectList(State.ToArray(), "StateID", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: What does the Index method on your HomeController look like?

Comment: index method given....please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 1):

500 error code means that mostly likely a runtime error was generated in your controller's action method. If you actually inspect the response in the `Net` tab of Firebug, it should tell you what the error was.

Off the cuff, for example, I can see that you have no check to determine if any `State` was actually returned from the query. It could potentially be null, and if it's null then you'll get runtime errors to the effect of "null property doesn't have this method" all over the place.

Comment: thanks tips. i am new in mvc so often making mistake. if u plzz run my code and tell the exact error then it will be very helpful. thanks

Comment: i have seen the net tab and saw all files were downloaded at client end properly. then problem occur when i change the country dropdown. i think problem lies in js code may be. plzz guide. thanks

Comment: Thomas, a 500 error means the error is server-side.  You need to show us the Index method on your HomeController if you want any help with this.

Comment: Debug your Index action and make sure everything is as you assume it should be (that `State` is not null, for one). Put the breakpoint at the beginning of the action and step through line-by-line to see where it fails. This is basic debugging procedure here, and it's something you should have done before you even came here.